# Add statelines to ZipChoropleth while preserving AK and HI as insets in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap, choropleth

## My goal:

Is to create a choropleth map based on zipcode data with the statelines shown. I am using the ChoroplethrZip package.

I successfully created my map using the following code and the output is **Map A**:

```
q1 <- c(0,1,10,25,100,500, Inf)
df_c <-cut(df,breaks=q1 ,right = FALSE ,labels = c("0","[1,10)","[10,25)","[25,100)","[100,500)",">500"))
df$value <- df_c
cols.blues <- brewer.pal(6,"Blues")
cols <- c("#ffffff",cols.blues[2:6])

choro             = ZipChoropleth$new(df)
choro$ggplot_scale = scale_fill_manual("Cases"
                                   ,values = cols
                                   ,drop=FALSE)
choro$ggplot_polygon = geom_polygon(aes(fill=value), color = NA)
map <- choro$render_nationwide()
```

Based on this post(http://www.arilamstein.com/blog/2015/09/10/user-question-how-to-add-a-state-border-to-a-zip-code-map/), I tried to add the state lines but the problem is the statemap draws Alaska and Hawaii with their correct scale and location. So I end up with **Map B**.

I can tweak the ZipChoropleth map to use the render function instead of render_nationwide, like this `map <- choro$render()`. This aligns AK and HI with the statelines as in **Map C**. But this is not what I want.

I tried it the other way. I used the StateChoropleth function to make the state map with AK and Hi resized and relocated to the lower left corner using this code.

```
outline = StateChoropleth$new(df_pop_state)
outline$ggplot_polygon = geom_polygon(aes(fill=NA, size=0.25), alpha=0.0)
outline$show_labels = FALSE
outline$add_state_outline = TRUE
out = outline$render()
```

The map I get is shown in **Map D**.

But I can't add Map A to Map D. I get this error **Error: Don't know how to add o to a plot**

I have been researching this for two days, any help will be great.

[image]